# Do there exist algorithms for which super computers are difficult to exceed personal computers in speed?

Tags: algorithms

Let me ask whether there exist algorithms for which super computers are difficult to exceed personal computers in speed or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The English of the question is hard to fathom. Do you mean, "are there algorithms which personal computers do faster than supercomputers?"

Comment: I am sorry for the English words. Yes, or personal computers do in 100th of the time of supercomputers ,but not 10000th.

Comment: OK thanks. The answer seems to assume this but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Again very sorry for my English. I wanted to say , "or personal computers do  100 times slower than supercomputers ,but not 10000 times slower".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any task that requires low latency such as playing video games. But anyway this depends on a type of supercomputer. There could be supercomputers designed for low latency and playing games as well.